# API FedEX "INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the input"

Tags: python, json, fedex

I'm trying to validade an address in FedEX API using Python 3.8 and it returns an error of invalid field value

First I connect to the Auth API

```
payload={"grant_type": "client_credentials",'client_id':Client_id,'client_secret':Client_secret}
url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token"
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
response=requests.post(url, data=(payload), headers=headers)
```

And it returns a message with the Auth token correctly

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInRM5U0F2eUs1ZVFBVTFzS5k","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3599,"scope":"CXS SECURE"}
```

Then I just get the token to use it in next transactions

```
token = json.loads(response.text)['access_token']
```

Then I prepare the next payload for address validation API

```
payload_valid_address = {
    "addressesToValidate": [
        {
    "address":
            {
            "streetLines": ["7372 PARKRIDGE BLVD"],
            "city": "Irving",
            "stateOrProvinceCode": "TX",
            "postalCode": "75063-8659",
            "countryCode": "US"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And send the request to the new endpoint with the given token

```
url = "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/address/v1/addresses/resolve"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'X-locale': "en_US",
    'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload_valid_address, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

and get the error

```
<Response [422]>
{"transactionId":"50eae03e-0fec-4ec7-b068-d5c456b64fe5","errors":[{"code":"INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the input"}]}
```

I have made inumerous tests and I don't get the invalid field.
Anyone know what is happening and can help?

Comment: FedEX uses OAuth 2.0 token authentication method to authorize the application and authenticate API requests.

Comment: Try using `string` object from `json` by: 
```import json

payload_valid_address = '''{
    "addressesToValidate": [
        {
    "address":
            {
            "streetLines": ["7372 PARKRIDGE BLVD"],
            "city": "Irving",
            "stateOrProvinceCode": "TX",
            "postalCode": "75063-8659",
            "countryCode": "US"
            }
        }
    ]
}''' 
```
PAYLOAD_VALID_ADDRESS = json.load(PAYLOAD_VALID_ADDRESS)

Comment: Same issue. I tried to use other endpoit API's with other payloads and I get the same issue. Other point is that the error 422 is not listed in FedEX documents and its Json Schema. I think the problem is not the payload but in the way that I'm accessing the API's or validating the token.

Comment: @FlavioAmadio Yeah, that's correct. Error 422 is not listed nor documented in Fedex. That's exaxctly what I'm getting on an a PHP implementation I'm doing now. Still trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: This (inscrutible) error means one of the types you are using is wrong.  Dump your json and compare with the schema.  For example, this will happen if it expects an array and you pass an object. Or it expects an object and you pass in an array.  Or it expects a number and you pass a string.  This sort of type mismach in your input data is what's causing this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

payload = json.dumps({input payload}) this works to prevent the response error 422
<Response [422]>

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it

For any reason, convert the string payload_valid_address to Json in 2 steps doesn't work

```
payload_valid_address = {....}
payload = json.dumps(payload_valid_address)
```

But if made in just one step it pass the API request

```
payload_valid_address = json.dumps({....})
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error and additionally had to use `json.loads(json_string)` when the json data contained key words like false, true or null.

```
import json

json_string = r'''{
  "accountNumber": {
    "value": "802255209"
  },
  "requestedShipment": {
    "shipper": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": 75063,
        "countryCode": "US"
      }
    },
    "recipient": {
      "address": {
        "postalCode": "m1m1m1",
        "countryCode": "CA"
      }
    },
    "shipDateStamp": "2020-07-03",
    "pickupType": "DROPOFF_AT_FEDEX_LOCATION",
    "serviceType": "INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY",
    "rateRequestType": [
      "LIST",
      "ACCOUNT"
    ],
    "customsClearanceDetail": {
      "dutiesPayment": {
        "paymentType": "SENDER",
        "payor": {
          "responsibleParty": null
        }
      },
      "commodities": [
        {
          "description": "Camera",
          "quantity": 1,
          "quantityUnits": "PCS",
          "weight": {
            "units": "KG",
            "value": 20
          },
          "customsValue": {
            "amount": 100,
            "currency": "USD"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "requestedPackageLineItems": [
      {
        "weight": {
          "units": "KG",
          "value": 20
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'''

data = json.loads(json_string)
data
```

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```